# MySQL query, join(?) and update column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in need about a MySQL query which happens to be far more complicated than any other I have ever made (I can barely use the simpliest queries really).

So, I have 2 tables. One has the columns (user, rank), the other has (user, vote).
In a PHP environment, I need to update the rank of a user in table1 based on the vote contained in table2. Something along the lines of "If user voted 1, add +50 to his rank. If user voted -1, add -50 to his rank. If user voted 2 add +200 to his rank."

I can do all the "if" work in PHP but would really need to have an efficient SQL query to get the data and manipulate the rank, because I'm already full of poorly optimized interrogations in my project.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: So there's a direct correlation between votes and ranks? So why store ranks at all?

Comment: because the impact of a vote on the rank is based on several different factors.

Comment: ...not all of which are directly related to data already stored in the table?

Comment: they are surely related, but not all data I need to calculate the rank is in the table

Answer (score 2):

Using an `insert...select` statements combined with an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, you should be able to do it in one go:

```
INSERT INTO userrank(user, rank)
SELECT v.user, sum(v.vote) * 50 as rank
FROM uservote v
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rank = v.rank
```

You could add a second statement, in case you want to remove a user's rank when all his votes are deleted:

```
DELETE FROM userrank r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM uservote v WHERE v.user = r.user)
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated :)